# Pass extra variable to Drupal Twig

Tags: twig, mailchimp, drupal-8, drupal-theming, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I need to pass extra variable to twig, below code loads `weekView` twig file where I can access node of `$week_id` but I need to access `$image_path` as well.

```
$week_id = $dynamic_week_id; //comes from different node
$image_path = $dynamic_image_path; //comes from different node

 $view_week_key = [
            'content',
            'this_week_wrapper',
            'this_week',
            'value',
        ];

$form_state->setValue($view_week_key, "<p>[mailchimp_campaign|entity_type=node|entity_id=" . $week_id . "|view_mode=weekView]</p>");
```

Answer (score 1):

What kind of twig you are using?
If it's a twig file of node you can get the image by using:

```
{{ file_url(node.field_name.entity.fileuri)}}
```